# issue with javascript code to accommodate multiple html select menus

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what I've got so farr..
The goal is to have a select menu displaying numbers from 0 to 9, with the value as the respective number, and to also incrementally number the select tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function more()
    {
    counter += 1;
    document.getElementById("options").innerHTML += ("<select name='" + counter + "'>");
    for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
        document.getElementById("options").innerHTML += ("<option value='" + i + "'>"+ i + "</option>");
        }
    document.getElementById("options").innerHTML += ("</select>");

    }



</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="options">
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter=0;
more();
</script>
</div>

<div id="more">
<button onClick='more()' style='color:blue;font-size:11px;font-family:verdana; cursor:pointer;'>more</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `select` element as a whole, otherwise it is invalid markup:

```
function more()
{
    counter += 1;
    var selectBody = '';
    selectBody += "<select name='" + counter + "'>";
    for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
       selectBody += "<option value='" + i + "'>"+ i + "</option>";
    }
    selectBody += "</select>";
    //Appending as a whole
    document.getElementById("options").innerHTML += selectBody;   
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut7fc/)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. In your line to add the actual option elements you were trying to append them to the div and not the select element. You needed to use `getElementsByName(counter)[0]` instead of `getElementById("options")` there.

```
function more() {
    counter += 1;
    document.getElementById("options").innerHTML += ("<select name='" + counter + "'>");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        document.getElementsByName(counter)[0].innerHTML += ("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
    document.getElementById("options").innerHTML += ("</select>");
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7xzEg/)**.